# WebAPI request query parameter values are null in .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a REST API controller in  new .NET CORE app.  If I make the following call: https://localhost/api/search?query=someText, I am able to execute the code below, so it looks like the routing is correct, however, query.query is always null.  I would expect the value to be "someText".

What is wrong here?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]SearchQuery query)
{
} 

public class SearchQuery
    {
        [FromQuery(Name = "query")]
        public string query { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Please try changing the parameter name in your Get action method from `SearchQuery query` to `SearchQuery model` to avoid ambiguity with the property name inside your model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your parameters names conflict causing an ambiguity, because they are all `query`.

If you have it like this, it will work:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]SearchQuery queryParam)
{
  // here you can use queryParam.query
} 

public class SearchQuery
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "query")]
    public string query { get; set; }

}
```

You can also made it to work changing your parameter `[FromQuery(Name = "query")]` name to something else than `query`, but in this case you will need to change your request query string according.